# Svelte automatic imports do not work in Visual Studio Code

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, auto-import

In preview application I was working on when I typed the name of the component. Like this:
I gave an import. Automatically added to script.

```
`<BaseSelect options={optionsDifficulty} defaultValue={defaultDifficultValue} on:change {handleDifficultChange}> </BaseRadio>
```

```
import BaseSelect from '$lib/Inputs/BaseSelect.svelte';
```

`

I did not write anything. It has just appeared. But in my new project it is not working. I need to write the import manually. Do you guys know how to setup this automatic import? I do not like autoimport way. Because I do not see the imports so I do not have control over it.

I tried autoimport as an extension, but it does not show list of imports.

My IDE is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It sounds like you're upset because of your IDE but you don't say what you're even using.

Comment: I edited my question. But I thought it was something I needed to install in the IDE.

Comment: The feature is called auto import. What is the difference between the old and the new project where it is working? [Here is some Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/12an2lc/sveltekit_and_vscode_importing_from_lib_no_ide/). Here is some [

Comment: I do not know what is the difference. I am not able to look into the preview project.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it. All the solutions were about adding to tsconfig.json. But I have javascript, not typescript. I added jsconfig.json (instead of tsconfig.json) in the main root of the project (next to package.json). And in it I added:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "$lib":["src/lib"],
            "$lib/*":["src/lib/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.svelte"]
}
```